# Change user status from checkbox laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the user status with a checkbox. If the checkbox is marked, the status should be one. Right now my change status function in the controller doesn't change anything at all. How do I make sure he sees the checkbox as a value, and that the checkbox marker changes when the value is 1. This is what I  have thus far:

in my view:

```html
<form action="{{ route('users.change_status', $user) }}" class="form" method="post">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                @method('PATCH')
                                <label>body</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="body" value="{{$user->status}}">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="button is-link is-outlined">Update</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

In my userController:

```js
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::get();
        return view('users',compact('users'));
    }


    public function change_status(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        dd($user);

        // Validate posted form data
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'status' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (!$validated) { return redirect()->back();}
        $user->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

And my routes in web.php:

```js
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
Route::patch('/change_status', [UserController::class, 'change_status'])->name('users.change_status');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding)

```
Route::patch('/change_status/{user}', [UserController::class, 'change_status'])->name('users.change_status');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use blade's if statements to add a `checked` attribute on the checkbox if the status is set, it can be as simple as checking if the value is truthy, which `1` is.

```
<form action="{{ route('users.change_status', $user) }}" class="form" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @method('PATCH')
    <label>body</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="body" value="{{$user->status}}" @if($user->status) checked @endif>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="button is-link is-outlined">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's a quick working [demo](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/e342d071-048c-4cf1-abc4-01aaf78c771f).

And as @Mohsen said, make sure you pass in the user so your controller has access to it.

Comment: I changed the route and used your code but it still doesn't work. The checkmark doesn't change after I press the update button and it doesn't change the status from 0 to 1 in my database

Comment: That's because an unchecked checkbox doesn't send any value to the post URL. You'll have to check if the value doesn't exist, or add a hidden input with the default value of `0` before the checkbox input that then checkbox overwrites when checked. Here's a [demo](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/0829d5fa-c4f8-4c8b-84cc-7397eb4f31e3) of how that works.